# Need help with geometry nodes instance textures not showing when going into rendered view

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have an object, with point distribute on it, geometry nodes. The points are instancing another object, with a transparent texture. (I used Transparent BSDF), when in the 'viewport shading' view, I see everything correctly. But when I go into rendered view, the instanced objects take on the texture from the object they're 'on'.
How can I fix this?
Thanks to anyone wanting to help me out here!

Extra information;

[image]

I have this leaf, used a plane to put the texture on, and made the black part of the image transparent with transparent BSDF and mix shader nodes.

[image]
[image]
I want to point distribute the the leafs onto the hedge. And that works;
However, when i try to view this in rendered view, the leafs completely disappear... they do not in eevee, only in cycles
[image]
.And when i apply the geometry node modifier, all the leafs take on the texture of the hedge. I suppose i don't really need to apply the geometry node modifier, but i want to see the leafs in cycles render. Thats my biggest concern. Thank you for the responses!

[Link to google drive, where you can download the file to help me out](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xfvhyPR9uSFCnsImUn9r8x4qTMYpIz_i?usp=sharing)

Comment: please share blend file or/and some screenshots

Comment: What do you mean "transparent texture" - do you mean a texture with transparent areas, or are you using a Transparent BSDF?

Comment: Please share a screenshot of your shader node

Comment: try to assign the material with the "material assign" node in gn node tree

Comment: I think explaining the problem might be too difficult, I'll add my blender file. Hopefully this will help!